# How to suppress message 'This workbook will be marked as final'

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Using VBA, when I set

```
workbook.Final = True
```

the message 'This workbook will be marked as final' appears. As I am trying to do this as batch this is becoming quite annoying. Furthermore users can click cancel which leads into an 'Unspecified automation error'

btw, Application.DisplayAlerts = False doesn't help here.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated...

Comment: `Displayalerts` works for me.

Comment: When do you set the `Final` and `DisplayAlerts` properties in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, setting DisplayAlerts to False seems to work after all.

Just realized that Excel will auto set it back to true as soon as the code finished. So we need to verify that DisplayAlerts is still False before using workbook.Final = True.

> If you set this property to False, **Excel sets this property to True**
> **when the code is finished**, unless you are running cross-process code.

[Microsoft VBA Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts)